# Why I need to add '&' when calling the function

Tags: c, pointers, tree, computer-science, double-pointer

```
 typedef struct sTree {
    int key;
    struct sTree* p;
    struct sTree* left;
    struct sTree* right;
} sTree;

typedef sTree* tree;

void treeInsert(tree* root);

int main(){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    tree *root = NULL;
    treeInsert(&root);
    return 0;
}

void treeInsert(tree* root){
    ......
}
```

I don't understand why I have to pass '&' when calling tree insert (&root instead of root).
I've created a struct representing a node of binary tree and I declared a pointer to the root of the tree as 'tree*'.
So 'root' is double pointer. The function 'treeInsert' expects a double pointer. If I pass simply 'root' it takes the value (NULL) else with the operator '&' it points correctly to the root. The problem is:
passing '&root' I'm not passing a triple pointer? Can someone explain why?

Comment: See [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/750178/15168) TL;DR — the answer's NO, with a possible exception for pointers to functions.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp look at the `void treeInsert(tree* root)` fingerprint. Typedef or not, `root` is ok for that function. We don't know how that function is implemented. Let's avoid guessing.

Comment: @davide is the compiler ok with passing `&root` to `treeInsert`?

Answer (score 0):

regarding:

```
treeInsert(&root);
```

the need for the `&` is because the function: `treeInsert()` will need to modify the contents of the pointer.  Without the `&` any assignment to that passed parameter will only change the parameter on the call stack and not the the contents of the parameter in `main()`

regarding:

```
tree *root = NULL;
```

Since `tree` is already a pointer, this results in (effectively)

```
tree ** root = NULL;
```

which will not accomplish what is needed.

A prime example of why a pointer should NOT be hidden in a `typedef` statement

the following proposed code is clear about what is wanted:

```
struct sTree 
{
    int key;
    struct sTree* p;
    struct sTree* left;
    struct sTree* right;
};

typedef struct sTree tree;

void treeInsert(tree** root);

int main( void )
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    tree *root = NULL;
    treeInsert(&root);
    return 0;
}

void treeInsert(tree** root)
{
    tree *localroot = *root; // now 'localroot' is a pointer to the variable `root` in function: `main()`
    ......
}
```

Comment: _"Since tree is already a pointer, this results in (effectively) `tree ** root = NULL;`"_. No: it results in `sTree ** root = NULL`.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni,  even so, `root` should NOT be a ** variable in `main()`